# Git Branch related issue on a team project

Tags: git, github

1. I have pushed code in my branch
2. then merged with the main branch
3. My teammate has also pushed & merged.
   Now I have to pull the updated project from the main branch to my vs code. How can I do this? I cannot configure these commands. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pull the latest version of the main branch, which includes your teammates changes, you need to checkout onto the main branch and do git pull. This will ensure that the branch has the latest changes. Then any new branch you create from main will have all of the changes.

So the commands are:

```
git checkout main
git pull origin main
```